# liipImagineBundle does not show my images filtered

Tags: image, symfony, bundle, symfony5, liipimaginebundle

Installed liipimagine using : composer require liip/imagine-bundle
I added this to my liip_imagine.yaml

```
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        test:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail:
                    size: [120, 90]
                    mode: outbound
```

then I added this to my index.html.twig

```
<img src="{{ asset('blogImages/' ~ blog.imageBlog | imagine_filter('test')) }}">
```

the images don't appear at all, before the usage of liipimagine bundle they were appearing perfectly fine.

I was expecting for the images to show in interface filtered with liipimagine filter.

Comment: Try to put this 'blogImages/' ~ blog.imageBlog between () like this ('blogImages/' ~ blog.imageBlog)

Comment: it didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. All you have to do is open xampp click on `config` of the service `Apache` then `PHP (php.ini)` search for `gd`

you'll find `;extension=gd` you have to remove the `;` save then restart services and it will work.

Comment: This is called "enable an extension"